# Error using quad in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an anonymous function in matlab: `f=@(x) x/(1+x^4)`. I want to integrate it from 0 to 1 with quad, but for some reason mpower is complaining that it can't take `x^4` because "Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix." If I replace `x^4` with `x*x*x*x`, I get "Error using ==> mtimes Inner matrix dimensions must agree." Here's the full error output.

```
??? Error using ==> mpower
Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.

Error in ==> intapprox>@(x)x/(1+x^4) at 4
f=@(x) x/(1+x^4);

Error in ==> quad at 77
y = f(x, varargin{:});

Error in ==> intapprox at 27
area = quad(f,0,1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `f=@(x) x./(1+x.^4);` i.e. `./` and `.^` since you don't want to do a matrix divide and power. Then I get

```
>> area = quad(f,0,1)
area =

    0.3927
```

Which is consistent with the analytical value of pi/8.